# Which type of Ajax should I post to a Rails 3.1 controller when creating records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a newsletter box that submits via ajax like this:

```
function ajax_subscribe(){
        $.ajax({
            url:    '/subscribe',
            type:   'post',
            data:   ({
                email: $('#email').val()
            }),

            success: function(msg){
                $('#newsletter_form').hide();
                $('#newsletter .done').removeClass('hide');
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see I'm currently using `type: 'post'`

Will that go to the `create` function in my controller automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great article on the default Rails routes: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

The routes will be the same regardless of whether you're using ajax or synchronous calls.